# Getting non-deterministic results from WITH RECURSIVE cte

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a recursive CTE that traverses all the records for a given ID, and does some operations between ordered records. Let's say I have customers at a bank who get charged a uniquely identifiable fee, and a customer can pay that fee in any number of installments:

```
WITH recursive payments ( 
         id
       , index
       , fees_paid
       , fees_owed
       )
  
  AS (
  
  SELECT id
       , index
       , fees_paid
       , fee_charged
    FROM table
   WHERE index = 1
    
   UNION ALL
    
  SELECT t.id
       , t.index
       , t.fees_paid
       , p.fees_owed - p.fees_paid 
    FROM table t
    JOIN payments p
      ON t.id = p.id
     AND t.index = p.index + 1
  )

  SELECT * 
    FROM payments 
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

The join logic seems sound, but when I join the output of this query to the source table, I'm getting non-deterministic and incorrect results.

This is my first foray into Snowflake's recursive CTEs.  What am I missing in the intermediate result logic that is leading to the non-determinism here?

Comment: It might help to provide sample data in the 2 tables, the results you are expecting, and the results you are getting.  This will help others attempt to duplicate the issue and resolve it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I definitely should have posted some sample data and the expected result.  Forgive me - I'm new to stackoverflow.  In peeling apart the layers and looking at the intermediate results, I think the CTE itself is not the problem, hence my frustration and confusion.  The non-determinism was coming from the view this query pulls from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is edited code, because in the anchor of you CTE you select the fourth column `fee_charged` which does not exist, and then in the recursion you don't sum the `fees paid` and other stuff, basically you logic seems rather strange.

So creating some random data, that has two different `id` streams to recurse over:

```
create or replace table data (id number, index number, val text);
insert into data 
  select * from values (1,1,'a'),(2,1,'b')
      ,(1,2,'c'), (2,2,'d')
      ,(1,3,'e'), (2,3,'f')
      v(id, index, val);
```

Now altering you CTE just a little bit to concat that strings together..

```
WITH RECURSIVE payments AS
(
  SELECT id
       , index
       , val
    FROM data
   WHERE index = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.id
       , t.index
       , p.val || t.val as val
    FROM data t
    JOIN payments p
      ON t.id = p.id
     AND t.index = p.index + 1
)
  SELECT * 
    FROM payments 
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

we get:

```
ID  INDEX   VAL
1   1       a
1   2       ac
1   3       ace
2   1       b
2   2       bd
2   3       bdf
```

Which is exactly as I would expect. So how this relates to your "it gets strange when I join to other stuff" is ether, your output of you CTE is not how you expect it to be.. Or your join to other stuff is not working as you expect, Or there is a bug with snowflake.

Which all comes down to, if the CTE results are exactly what you expect, create a table and join that to your other table, so eliminate some form of CTE vs JOIN bug, and to debug why your join is not working.

But if your CTE output is not what you expect, then lets help debug that.

Comment: Hugely helpful, thank you.  Going through step by step, I believe that the CTE results are indeed correct, as you speculated.